# Invalid File error when uploading file with a PHP script

Tags: php, file-upload

I have been trying various methods to upload a file to a wordpress site uploads directory (I gave it 777 permissions now just to be sure that I don't get permission problems). 
I have a custom php plugin where the code is placed.

I tried using wordpress functions but they don't seem to work.

So now I got a snippet of code in php that should handle the file upload (submitted by a form).

Here is my handling code:

```
        //image upload handling
        $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["editfile"]["name"]);
        $extension = end($temp);
        if ((($_FILES["editfile"]["type"] == "image/gif")
            || ($_FILES["editfile"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
            || ($_FILES["editfile"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
            || ($_FILES["editfile"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
            || ($_FILES["editfile"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
            || ($_FILES["editfile"]["type"] == "image/png"))
            && ($_FILES["editfile"]["size"] < 5000000)
            && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
        {
            if ($_FILES["editfile"]["error"] > 0)
            {
                $tim_core_edit_company_page .= "Return Code: " . $_FILES["editfile"]["error"] . "<br>";
            }
            else
            {
                $tim_core_edit_company_page .= "Upload: " . $_FILES["editfile"]["name"] . "<br>";
                $tim_core_edit_company_page .= "Type: " . $_FILES["editfile"]["type"] . "<br>";
                $tim_core_edit_company_page .= "Size: " . ($_FILES["editfile"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
                $tim_core_edit_company_page .= "Temp file: " . $_FILES["editfile"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

                if (file_exists(wp_upload_dir() . $_FILES["editfile"]["name"]))
                {
                    $tim_core_edit_company_page .= $_FILES["editfile"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
                }
                else
                {   
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["editfile"]["tmp_name"],
                    "upload/" . $_FILES["editfile"]["name"]);
                    $tim_core_edit_company_page .= "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["editfile"]["name"];
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $tim_core_edit_company_page .= "Invalid file";
        }
```

And here is the form that is used to submit the file:

```
<form action="' . site_url('/edit-company/?cid=' . $_GET['cid'] 
                                            . '&lid=' . $_GET['lid'] 
                                            . '&cname=' . $_GET['cname'] . '&editcompany=1&todb=1' ) . '" method="post">
                                                <label><b>Company Name:</b></label> <input type="text" name="editname" value="' . $company->company_name . '">
                                                <label><b>Address:</b></label> <input type="text" name="editaddress" value="' . $company->company_address . '">
                                                <label><b>Telephone:</b></label> <input type="text" name="edittelephone" value="' . $company->company_telephone . '">
                                                <label><b>Fax:</b></label> <input type="text" name="editfax" value="' . $company->company_fax . '">
                                                <label><b>Email:</b></label> <input type="text" name="editemail" value="' . $company->company_email . '">
                                                <label><b>Website:</b></label> <input type="text" name="editwebsite" value="' . $company->company_website . '">
                                                <label><b>Logo:</b></label> <input type="file" name="editfile" id="file">
                                                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                                            </form>
```

The response I get is "Invalid File". I tired uploading all kinds of images and the result is always the same.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

UPDATE:

I followed the advice to add enctype="multipart/form-data" to the form and obviously the invalid file error is gone now. 
However, I still don't see the upload in the wp-content/uploads directory. I see that it has been last modified now, so the script did alter it somehow, but I don't see the actual uploaded file anywhere. I think it might have something to do with wordpress processing the uploads directory.

Comment: add attribute enctype="multipart/form-data" in form tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form tag to send files with the form.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to have solved the issue! Now I don't get an error. However the file is still not seen in the uploads directory. It created the folders in the upload dir and I can see that they have been modified now, but I don't see the actual file there. Very strange.

Comment: It works, I changed the upload directory. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Could be a problem with write privileges on the server.